Resistor after voltage divider changing the maths?
I would like to get the correct voltage value after a voltage divider.
In some way R7 is affecting the estimated voltage output value but I don't know how.
My math, (Vout) calculated after R7:
Vout = (5V x 2.4) / (22.1 + 2.4) = 0.49 Volts.
But I get a different value because R7 is not included in my formula.
How I can include R7 in my equation?


Why such a large R7? Or why include it at all?

How different is the measured value from your calculated, expected value?

Your formula is correct if you neglect ADC input impedance, and the source impedance the ADC needs to work correctly. Why is the 10k resistor there to begin with, and with what measuring tool you get an incorrect measurement, is it a multimeter, oscilloscope or the ADC measurement result?

The input to the converter is a switched sample & hold (see Figure 28 in the data sheet). The source impedance is most likely too high (about 12k). See if placing a capacitor from pin-3 to ground helps. Something in the range of 1 nF to 10 nF should suffice. The capacitor will supply the necessary current to charge the input capacitance during switching.
You can also try reducing the value of R7, perhaps to zero. Keep the capacitor for pin-3 to ground as this is still good practice.

The input leakage current in the spec (near the bottom of page 3) is +/-1ua.  Through 10K, this should cause a difference of +/-0.01V, which is negligible.  It should also not affect the divider significantly, since the bias current in the divider is ~200uA.
Measure the voltage on each side of R7; they should be the same (within 0.01V).  If not, the ADC is likely malfunctioning, or there is something else attached to the input.

The behaviour of the R7 in this circuit is kind of weird, it must but something when R7 interact with the ADS leakage current. I found that the best solution is to remove R7 from the circuit because it does't have any special role there, after that all is working as it's spected.
Thank you all!

R7 is not necessary.  R7 and the sample-and-hold capacitance (12pF) form an RC filter whose time constant must be very small with respect to the sample time (0.64uS) or the measured voltage will be lower than the input voltage (the voltage divider Vo or ~0.4897959 volts in this case). Note that the sample-and-hold current is drawn through R134 as well, so it too affects the sample-and-hold charge time.  If the input voltage divider can not have a lower impedance (due to circuit efficiency. etc.), then use a unity gain amp between the voltage divider and ADC AIN. Another option is to use a capacitor in parallel with R139 that is large with respect to the sample-and-hold capacitance.   Also note that the I(leakage) into AIN is 1uA which will have the affect of dropping some voltage in the voltage divider and R7.
